# Would GPS work above the GPS satellites?

Tags: gps

If a rocket carrying a GPS device ascended *above* the height of the orbit of the GPS satellites (about 20,000km), what height would the GPS device report?

Would it keep reporting the correct height as it passed through the orbit height, or would it start reporting a reducing height.

In simple math, if GPS satellite height is `h`, at height `h + x`, would a GPS device report its height as `h + x` or `h - x`, or something else?

Comment: My unsupported answer would be: Assuming you mean `x` to be the distance the satellite is above `h`, it would incorrectly report `h - x`. I'm also not sure that the GPS signal would be received by the satellite as the transmitters may all be specifically targeted downwards.

Comment: See [What is the deepest position in space we can get a GPS signal?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/5551/49), [How far up have satellites used GNSS for positioning, and how does the precision degrade with altitude?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/565/49), [In LEO, what is the precision of GNSS-based position compared to traditional methods?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/563/49) and a few other questions tagged as [tag:gps] and/or [tag:gnss].