# Can the James Webb Space Telescope's position be determined using GNSS? And if not, how is this done?

Tags: james-webb-telescope, tracking, gps, gnss

As far as I know, the recently [launched](https://www.jwst.nasa.gov/) [James Webb Space Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Webb_Space_Telescope) will be positioned at [1,500,000](https://webb.nasa.gov/content/about/orbit.html) km of the Earth, orbiting Sun-Earth L2 Lagrange point at roughly 4x the distance between the Earth and the Moon.

Usual positioning satellites constellations (GPS, GALILEO, GLONASS, BEIDOU,...) are located at roughly 20,000 km, which is ~ 0.013 of the JWST final position.

On the basis of this observation, I'm then wondering; could the position of the JWST be known accurately enough using GNSS satellites at such a great distance? I'm intuitively convinced that positional signals may be too collinear (if they still exist with a good  enough [S/N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio)) to be precise enough at such distance. But I may be wrong.

And if not, how is the position of the telescope known at any given moment? Or how is the instrument positioned (i.e. relative to which reference frame,...? Maybe it's not an Earth-centric frame as we are used to down here)?

Comment: While I don't know exactly how the JWST navigates (I suspect it uses an inertial navigation system) I doubt that any GNSS signals will be able to be received by it.  Keep in mind that all such satellites have antennas that direct their signals toward the earth.  So none of the antennas would ever be pointing at the JWST to begin with.

Comment: Would [space.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Different but related (most have been closed as dupes but all have helpful information): [How far up have satellites used a GNSS for positioning, and how does the precision degrade with altitude?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/565/12102) and [What is the deepest position in space we can get a GPS signal?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/5551/12102) and [Has GPS been used beyond GEO?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14737/12102) and [Would GPS work above the GPS satellites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/10447/12102)

Comment: Also different but related: [Can the James Webb Space Telescope basically manage its own orbit if necessary?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18504/12102) and [Exact speed/distance of JWST (& others in L1/L2 halo) from Earth; is it measured any differently than for more distant deep-space missions?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/57525/12102)

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer...

Considering:

https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2018/01/180111223914.htm

> NASA engineers has demonstrated fully autonomous X-ray navigation in space

NICER/SEXTANT

https://www.asterlabs.com/publications/2006/Sheikh_et_al,_AIAA_JGCD_Jan_Feb_2006.pdf

> Spacecraft Navigation Using X-Ray Pulsars

China's XPNAV 1

[Is NICER/SEXTANT the first civilian "spacecraft" to determine it's own position in space without GPS or uplinked data?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24448/40489)

[How can spacecraft navigate without contact from Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/942/40489)

[Satellite Position](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21336/40489)

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20190000639

> Predicted Performance of an X-Ray Navigation System for Future Deep Space and Lunar Missions

https://physicsworld.com/a/x-ray-pulsars-plot-the-way-for-deep-space-gps/

> X-ray pulsars plot the way for deep-space GPS

https://www.wired.com/story/nasa-just-proved-it-can-navigate-space-using-pulsars-where-to-now/

> NASA Just Proved It Can Navigate Space Using Pulsars. Where to Now?

https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1704/1704.03316.pdf

> Pulsar Positioning System

I had erroneously assumed that JWST would make use of XNAV. But no.

Maybe, probably, due to the time when the project was first started and the length of time it took to get to launch, XNAV probably wasn't matured enough to get on board.

So instead there is this:

> **Navigation Concepts for the James Webb Space Telescope**

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20040082113

> The  Mission  Engineering  and  Systems  Analysis  Division  at  the  Goddard  Space  Flight  Center  (GSFC)  is  supporting  the  JWST project by developing navigation concepts that meet nominal orbit determination accuracy requirements on the order of  50  km  in  position  and  20  millimeters  per  second  (mm/s)  in  velocity  (3-sigma).

> These  requirements  are challenging  because  of  the  unusually  large  solar  radiation  pressure  (SRP)  forces  that  will  be  experienced  by  the  spacecraft  and  the  frequent  attitude  reorientations  and  unbalanced  momentum  unloads  that  are  planned  for  this  mission.

> This paper evaluates ... approaches for meeting the navigation requirements:

- **Ground  navigation**  using  **standard  range**  and/or  **Doppler  measurements**  from  the  **Deep  Space  Network**  (DSN), which is the *current mission baseline*
- Onboard navigation using the **communications hardware and Sun sensor** *baselined for this mission*
- Onboard navigation using **optical celestial navigation sensors** that can measure the angle between the Earth and the Moon or a star and the Moon.

> The ground navigation approach processes standard range and Doppler measurements from the *Deep Space  Network*.

> The  onboard  navigation  approach  processes  celestial  object  measurements  and/or  ground-to-spacecraft  Doppler  measurements  to  autonomously  estimate  the  spacecraft’s  position  and  velocity  and  Doppler  reference frequency.

> The  ground  navigation  approach  provides  stable  navigation  solutions  using  a  **tracking  schedule  of  one  30-minute  contact  per  day**.

> The  onboard  navigation  approach  that  uses  only  optical  quality  celestial  object  measurements  provides stable autonomous navigation solutions.

So, the answer seems to be a combined ground and onboard navigation approach making use of the DSN.

..and not GNSS

So, whilst celestial GPS via Pulsars seems to be the way forward, they do not seem to be on JWST..

Further:

Also see this answer regarding using GPS beyond Earth:

https://space.stackexchange.com/a/567/40489

Furthest distance that GPS was utilised from Earth is around 70k km.

and this answer for self navigation in deep space:

https://space.stackexchange.com/a/12138/40489

> Probes don't locate themselves. We do.

> location of a probe is measured by ground control, using data from the probe.

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20080030196/downloads/20080030196.pdf

> Ranging is required for JWST, using alternate ground stations in the southern and northern hemisphere.

> The NASA Spectrum office objected to provide more than the 10
> MHz band in X-band range and suggested using Ka-band. JWST project decided to move to K-band and have one (1) 4-hour contact per day for communication and ranging.

https://www.esa.int/Enabling_Support/Operations/ESA_Ground_Stations/ESA_to_pick_up_as_Webb_phones_home

> ESA to pick up as Webb phones home

https://www.esa.int/ESA_Multimedia/Images/2019/02/Ultra-precise_navigation

> Ultra-precise navigation

> "How not to lose a spacecraft"

[image]

https://www.esa.int/Enabling_Support/Preparing_for_the_Future/Discovery_and_Preparation/Deep_space_communication_and_navigation

https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/002029400804100302

> For near-earth space explorers, a variety of autonomous navigation methods have been proposed and explored, including a magnetometer-based
> navigation method, Global Position System (GPS), inter-satellite
> link, and celestial navigation method.

> However, for deep space explorers, celestial navigation is the only feasible way.

Comment: voluminous answer with lots of goodies and gems! I have a bounty on [Exact speed/distance of JWST (& others in L1/L2 halo) from Earth; is it measured any differently than for more distant deep-space missions?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/57525/12102) but the bounty message is pretty clear about what I'm hoping to see. Of course the OP's expectations may not be exactly the same.

Comment: Based on what I've read, with JWST being the first L2 mission to be defined as a high data rate mission (270gb daily), a lot of ground services seemed to have been upgraded to cope with this and leads me to think yes, while it is not measured any differently it is perhaps measured more accurately due to the upgrades. OTTOMH though

Comment: "270gb daily" Yikes! Let me know when you're ready for a question about a first high data rate Lagrange point mission.

Comment: Apologies, forgot to capitalise, 270 Gb :P